# Is there anyway to use pseudo-streaming with wowza?

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

Is there anyway to use progressive download or HTTP pseudo-streaming with wowza ? to get the buffer bar on jwplayer ?

Comment: For M3U8 (HLS), or HTTP served MP4 files?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to progressive download as per [this article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download) (AKA pseudo-streaming), then no, Wowza does not support it. It's been planned but still not implemented.
Check Wiki though - it has plenty of solutions for PD.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is. You need to enable the `cupertinostreamingpacketizer` in your Application.xml, open port 80 in your `VHost.xml`:

```
<Port>1935,8089,80,554</Port>
```

and then set up your JW Player (the free version does not support this feature, I think only Premium does) so that the `file` property is is like this pattern:

```
http://yourserver/application/stream/playlist.m3u8
```

You can find an [example Application.xml here with cupertino enabled](https://github.com/jantekb/wowzatoolbox-examples/blob/master/wrench/01-simple-authentication/wowza/conf/wrenchexample1/Application.xml).